# Split Django into apps

Tags: python, django

I am thinking about how to split my website into smaller reusable apps.  I've finally figured out something and need your opinion.

My main problem was that each app uses `Profile` model.  This is of course a snippet of my work with the most important parts.

```
# App Userdata
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Photo(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(BaseProfile)
    url = models.URLField()

# App Social Connect
class SocialConnectProfile(models.Model):
    pass

class SocialConnect(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(SocialConnectProfile)

# App Forum
class ForumProfile(models.Model):
    pass

class Question(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(ForumProfile)

class Answer(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(ForumProfile)
    question = models.ForeignKey(ForumProfile)

# App Base
class Profile(BaseProfile, SocialConnectProfile, ForumProfile):
    pass
```

What I am worrying about is that there are 5 tables with a one-to-one relationship. 
What do you think?  Are there any better options?

Yes, the code has been pretty much simplified. Each app has many models indeed. (`BaseProfile` has `8`, `SocialConnect` only `1`, `Forum` `18`)

My target is to extract them as Python-Django components in future, but I haven't done it before.

I want to project them in this way now to save time in future with new applications or extending existing one, but I am not sure  if it's the best approach.

Comment: Why don't you just use BaseProfile? None of your other classes seem to add anything.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I would guess the specifics of the other models have been removed for clarity.

Comment: @JamesKhoury, perhaps. In that case I think the problem has been simplified past the point of being able to evaluate possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends really on how you will use those models.
For example if you always, always get question object then find the answers that belong to it. there is no point adding profile relation with answers models and keep it to questions only.

If in rare cases (not in loops) you might deal with an answer without getting its question object first, its still ok to do answer.question.profile